# Pyspark error while querying cassandra to convert into dataframes

Tags: cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the following error while executing the command:

```
user = sc.cassandraTable("DB NAME", "TABLE NAME").toDF()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 60, in toDF
    return sqlContext.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 333, in createDataFrame
    schema = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio)
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 220, in _inferSchema
    raise ValueError("Some of types cannot be determined by the "
ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling
```

Comment: After getting into source code level of pyspark I found out the error was because at the time of creation of dataframes, pyspark checks if any of the field in the first 100 rdds has continuous null value, if it finds null values continuously for 100 records for a particular field it throws this error.

Answer (score 2):

Load into a Dataframe directly this will also avoid any python level code for interpreting types.

```
sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(keyspace="ks",table="tb").load()
```